# In scala, avoid stack overflow when implementing functional style repeatUntil

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement `repeatUntil` in a functional way in scala and am wondering if there's a way to avoid a stack overflow while still having nice functional code. Here's what I have:

```
  def repeatUntil[T](f: => T, d: Duration, t: Int)(
    implicit ex: ScheduledExecutorService,
    ec: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
    delayedFuture(f, d).recoverWith {
      case e: Throwable => {
        if (t == 0) Failure(e).asInstanceOf[Future[T]]
        else repeatUntil(f, d, t - 1)
      }
    }
  }
```

where `d` is the delay in between attempts, `t` is the maximum number of attempts, and `delayedFuture` uses the supplied `ScheduledExecutorService` to execute `f` with delay `d`. I'm worried this has the potential for stack overflow if `t` is large and many (thousands) of unsuccessful attempts are made, leading to a very deep call stack. How can I do this without consuming much stack, but maximally adhering to functional programming principles?

Comment: Not sure about Scala in specific, but most functional languages will optimize this code into a tail-recursive call.

Comment: This won't overflow - no recursion is happening directly on the stack. Every execution of `repeatUntil` simply queues a future, it never calls itself directly.

Comment: `Failure(e).asInstanceOf[Future[T]]` won't work—you'll get a class cast exception because `Failure` isn't a `Future`. You probably want `Future.failed(e)`.